# Fiware Orion-LD Auto Increment Entity Id

Tags: fiware-orion

An Entity Id is required for each new entity in the broker.
In NGSI-LD the format for the Entity Id is `urn:ngsi-ld:TemperatureSensor:001`.
Is it possible to somehow autoincrement the number of the Entity so that the new Entity can be created programmatically?
For example, provide something like `urn:ngsi-ld:TemperatureSensor:*` and the new Entity can be created with an auto-incremented Entity Id.
Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id should be generated by the application itself. You have multiple ways of generating unique ids but I would recommend ids that have some semantics behind so that you can, for instance, infer from an id in which area the sensor is located, who the owner is, etc.